# Is it possible to load configuration from a Server in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

A quick question: In Java/Spring/Spring Boot world I know it is possible to have your server load their configuration from a "config server" instead of files in the instance or environment variables.
I am talking of spring-cloud-config-server.

Would it be possible to do the same thing in Rails?
Is there an extension or gem that would allow me to pull config from a KV storage or maybe from a remote storage (S3 for example) on instances starting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider: In Kubernetes you often load the configuration from the [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) which is a form of configuration server, so yes, you can. There are other systems in common use as well. For Rails you just need to stamp out the required `config/*.yml` files, something easily done with a quick Ruby wrapper script.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the comment.
Would you have a more in detail solution for the second part? Is it possible to provide those config file remotely and have the rails server fetch them before load?